# Set up a forwarding email account with Gmail for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I want to create a forwarder email address in Gmail for Business instead of having to create/pay for another email account at the same domain.

I have an email address, mail@example.com and I've set up my MX records in my domain to point to Gmail for all mail. I'm using Gmail for Business. Got that all working fine.

I'd also like to set up a secondary email: admin@example.com. But I don't really need any storage for that email and I'd rather not pay for it -- the account will receive so little traffic that it isn't really worth it to pay for an entire second account. I'd prefer if that account was just a dummy account that was only going to forward to mail@example.com. Is this possible with MX records or Gmail for Business?

I'm looking at the Email Routing config section for Email in the Google Apps control panel. Not sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: an alternate solution is to use [plus addressing](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12096)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MX records control only the server direction (i.e. messages sent to `@example.com` will be handled by the server located at `123.123.123.123`). It's the local mail server that decides that `admin@example.com` and `mail@example.com` correspond to the same inbox. Google uses the term `nickname` for forwarded addresses.

In order to create a nickname for an existing user/inbox in Google Apps, you need to do the following:

1. Go to your Google Apps admin dashboard
2. Click on `Organization and users` in the blue navigation menu on top of the page
3. Click on the user, to which you want to assign a nickname
4. In the User information tab (the default one) click on `Add a nickname` (it's right below `Email quota`)

Comment: what's unsaid here is that you can certainly [add domains](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53295) and email for an account like "username@" will work for all domains, but they run under the same Apps instance

Comment: @zanlok: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: it's an alternate method.. add another domain (which costs at the registrar, but is free as far as your Apps account handling it)

Answer (score 5):

I have just needed to do this myself, and the answer is not obvious, but is elegant; it can certainly be done.

What I am assuming here is that where you would like `admin@your-domain.com` forwarded to, is not necessarily a user account on the Google Apps business account. So `admin@example.com` is an external user. You just want to forward emails sent to a specific email address, and not necessarily store them in any mailbox on the Google Apps business account.

The answer is to use *groups*. You can set up a group just like a user, with nicknames as needed on as many or few domains as you have linked to your business account. You can then add any number of recipients to that group. The recipient list may include external email addresses as well as - or instead of - internal mailboxes.

When setting the group up, ensure you tick the box *"Also allow anyone on the internet to post messages"* and that will expose the group publicly as an email route.

This meets your stated requirement, as a group can be set up and act as a generic and flexible mail forwarder, without it requiring a new mailbox to be purchased.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! It wasn't obvious how to find the Groups page, but in the Admin Console I found it by just using the search at the top of the page (searching for "Groups") and then selecting "Add New Group" from the results.

Answer (score 2):

From what you're describing, it seems that the easier solution for this is to just [create an alias (or Nickname, in Apps parlance) for that email address within Google Apps](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?answer=182527). It'll act, functionally, exactly the same as a forward and send-as address.

Find the user account in question, click "Add A Nickname," and you should be off to the races.